# Relating a 1:M from CSV file to Shapefile and exporting?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins

I have a shapefile with 3 different statations, in addition to a CSV with time data and multiple records for each station, based on time.

Shapefile dbf:

```
ID    Station
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

CSV:

```
Station     V1      Year
  A         10      2000
  A         13      2001
  A         13      2002
  B         15      2000
  B         23      2001
  B         31      2002
  C         22      2000
  C         31      2001
  C         31      2002
```

Is there anyway to join to the CSV to the shapefile so I can display time based data?

I've tried the Make Query Table but this still doesn't add the spatial information to the CSV. I'm using ArcMap 10.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called a [pivot table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/pivot-table.htm) which:

> Creates a table from the input table by reducing redundancy in records
>   and flattening one-to-many relationships.